# SAS - count of records which appear in both datasets (large data)

Tags: sas

Consider I have two datasets:

```
data dataset_1;
   input CASENO X;
   datalines;
1 100
2 200
3 300
;

data dataset_2;
   input CASENO Y;
   datalines;
2 200000
3 300000
;
```

I'm looking to find how many CASENOs appear in both lists: in the example above, I would get 2.

My data is very large. It is taking a long time to get this sort of result by using a merge.

```
data result;
    merge dataset_1 (in = a) and dataset_2 (in = b);
    by CASENO;
    if a and b;
RUN;
```

I'm looking for a more efficient way -

edit: for clarity, is there a way to return the number of matches in two datasets without SAS having to write out the resulting file?

Comment: It doesn't get much more efficient than that -- improvements will come from hardware, settings and options.  Can you add any of these to your question ?  Show the log for the data step ? Use `options msglevel=I fullstimer;` before the step. Show the `Proc CONTENTS` output for each data set.  What is the system hardware ?  Are either of the datasets not on local disk ?  Did you try data set option `KEEP=CASENO` so only the caseno is in the pdv ?  Are their any data set indices being used to allow the merge to occur ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the datasets are already sorted, the data step merge is incredibly efficient.  It passes over each row in each table exactly once.  Of course, if you just want the *count*, you don't need to output all of the rows to a dataset, you can just:

```
data _null_;
    merge dataset_1 (in = a keep=caseno) dataset_2 (in = b keep=caseno) end=eof;
    by CASENO;
    if a and b then count+1;
    if eof then call symputx('count',count);
RUN;
```

This will be much faster to run since you're not writing anything out.  I also add KEEP statements (as Tom points out in comments) to the incoming datasets to only read in the by variable, this produces a speed-up of about 10%.

If the datasets are *indexed*, you have some additional options that will be faster as they will be doing index scans (such as using SQL).  But sorted, non-indexed tables, it's hard to improve on the data step merge.

Comment: Use of `KEEP=` dataset option could also help. If data source is external DBMS then it would greatly reduce size of result set returned from DBMS to SAS to process.

Comment: If it's external DBMS I think the answer will be somewhat different anyway (as there may be other, better solutions involving pass-through).  IIRC KEEP= won't matter on a SAS centric solution, since it's not writing anything out, no?

Comment: For SAS datasets `KEEP=` will have a small effect, but mainly in CPU time to move values already in memory from the read buffer to the data step variables. Since this is an IO bound problem not really any visible effect on run time.

Comment: I take it back; I did some tests and it looks like KEEP matters even for SAS datasets here, to the tune of about 10% faster when there are 10 other variables dropped beyond the ID.  That surprises me, but it's a meaningful difference.  (My storage is fast enough that it's not actually IO-bound,  though.)

Comment: I have to say I'm a bit surprised the SAS compiler doesn't optimize this, really; it seems like an obvious optimization.

Comment: I don’t think the data step compiler optimizes much. In fact  I’m not sure if it does any optimization??

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
proc sql;
   select count(caseno) as Number from dataset_1 where caseno in (select caseno from dataset_2);
quit;
```